# Calculate the mean after filtering and groupby

Tags: r, group-by, pipe

I have a large dataframe of message exchanges that looks like this:

```
structure(list(from = c(1, 8, 3, 3, 8, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 8, 4, 
1, 4, 8, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 8, 1, 4, 8), to = c(8, 3, 8, 54, 3, 
4, 1, 6, 7, 1, 4, 3, 8, 8, 1, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 1, 4, 3, 8, 1, 3
), time = c(63200, 81282, 81543, 81548, 81844, 82199, 82514, 
82711, 82739, 82814, 82936, 83889, 84207, 84427, 85523, 85545, 
86883, 87187, 87701, 89004, 89619, 92662, 93384, 93443, 94042, 
94203), month = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

I'm aiming to calculate the average of the differences in time between the first and the last message someone gets in a day.

So, what I'm aiming is to filter the dataset by an index if it is present either on column "to" of "from", group by day using both the month ("month") and the number of the day in the month ("day"), then I want to calculate the difference between the first and the last message in each day and then I want to average those differences.

At the end I should get a dataframe with the indexes and the daily average for each index. Like this:

```
index      avg
1     1 9429.333
2     3 2590.667
3     4 1982.000
4     8 7338.000
```

The value for 1 is the average of the differences between the max and min of time for each day: 19164 (for day 1 in month 2), 4251(for day 2 in month 4) and 4423 (for day 15 in month 6).(Note: when the difference is equal to 0 the number should be excluded from the average as in day 3 month 4 for index 8)

Right now I'm trying this, but it does not work

```
dur<-function(x)max(x)-min(x)  #The function to calculate the difference. In other cases I need to use other functions of my own

#index are the Names of the indexes for which I want the calculation
index <- c(1, 3, 4, 8)
names(index) <- index

index %>%
 map_dfr(~ df %>% filter(from == .x | to == .x) %>% group_by (month,day) %>% 
     summarize(result = dur(time)) %>% 
      summarize(mdur = mean(result)) ,.id = "index")`
```

The one below works to calculate the time difference for all messages, but I also need the daily average

```
index %>% 
  map_dfr(~ df %>% 
        filter(from == .x | to == .x) %>% 
        summarize(result = dur(time)),
        .id = "index")
```

Comment: (1) You need to define `index`. (2) Based on your input, how does your expected output look like?

Comment: I´ve defined the index, also added an expected output and an explanation of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(from = c(1, 8, 3, 3, 8, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 8, 4, 1, 4, 8, 1, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 8, 1, 4, 8, 2 ,3), 
           to = c(8, 3, 8, 54, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 1, 4, 3, 8, 8, 1, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 1, 4, 3, 8, 1, 3, 5, 8), 
           time = c(63200, 81282, 81543, 81548, 81844, 82199, 82514, 82711, 82739, 82814, 82936, 83889, 84207, 84427, 85523, 85545, 86883, 87187, 87701, 89004, 89619, 92662, 93384, 93443, 94042, 94203, 12402, 24932), 
           month = c(2, 2, 2, 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6, 9, 9), 
           day =   c(1, 1, 1, 15, 15, 22, 22, 22, 25, 25, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 15, 15, 15, 18, 18, 18, 9, 9))

df2 <- df %>% group_by(day, month) %>% summarise(f = first(time), l = last(time)) %>% mutate(diff = l - f) %>% group_by(month) %>% summarise(mt = sum(diff)/length(which(diff!=0)))
```

This gives:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  month      mt
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     2  4806.5
2     4  1834.5
3     6  2262.5
4     9 12530.0
```

Is this what you are after?

Although you have mentioned something about a person, your data does not include a **person** column, so I assume this is data from the same person. If you have multiple people, it's just a matter of applying this code to each person separately.

Comment: I´ve edited my question to make it clearer. I need the average of the differences by day and by index.  Columns from and to are needed to filter the datasbase by the index (I only need the messages including that index to do later calculations), columns month and day are needed then to group by specific days (day 1 month 2, is like saying February 1st). I need to calculate the difference for each day and then average those to get the value of 1 index. I need to do it over the complete list in index

Comment: I have a few questions: 

(1) Can you please give a proper sample of your data? Maybe spanning 3 months? 

(2) The way I understand it: 
(i) you need a daily difference column between last and first message times and 
(ii) then a monthly (index) average excluding zero differences, am I right? 

(3) What is the difference between index and month? Is 'index' just a counter variable for months?

Comment: (1) I´ve included a larger dataset with 4 different days as example.  (2) yes, but this is a only an intermediate step to then calculate the average. At the end, I do not need these individual numbers. Individual days are identified using both "month" and "day" columns. If we use only "day" we will be mixing info from different months (One message might be of the 1st of February and the other of the 1st of March)  (3) I just need the average of every single day. (4) The dataset is about messages exchanges within people. The index is a list with all the persons for which I want the calculation

Comment: In common words, Imagine you are person number 3. I need to filter to get all the  messages involving you (so with 3 either in "to" or "from"). Then, I need to know for each day how much time elapsed between the first and last message. Then I just need the average all of those daily differences (excluding 0´s). And I need this calculation to be done to everyone in the index list.